# 'mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property' when properties with the same name exist in both parent and child entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm on Spring Boot v1.5.3 and when I use Hibernate inheritance, `AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property` occurs when there are properties with the same name in both parent and child entities.

For example:

```
Apple => RedApple
      => GreenApple
      => etc.
Tree  => RedAppleTree
      => GreenAppleTree
      => etc.
```

```java
// Tree.java

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"apples"})
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Tree {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

```java
// RedAppleTree.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
@DiscriminatorValue("RED")
public class RedAppleTree extends Tree {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "tree")
    private List<RedApple> apples;
}
```

```java
// Apple.java

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Apple {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Colour colour;

    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Tree tree;
}
```

```java
// RedApple.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "apple")
@DiscriminatorValue("RED")
public class RedApple extends Apple {
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private RedAppleTree tree;
}
```

```java
// Colour.java

public enum Colour {
    RED,
    GREEN,
}
```

`Apple.tree` and `RedApple.tree` exist at the same time. In parent `Apple` the type is `Tree`; in child `RedApple` it's `RedAppleTree`.

Now when the project runs, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.dao.RedApple.tree in com.example.demo.dao.RedAppleTree.apples
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main (DemoApplication.java:13)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.dao.RedApple.tree in com.example.demo.dao.RedAppleTree.apples
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass (CollectionBinder.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass (CollectionBinder.java:719)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass (CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses (InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses (InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory (SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet (AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main (DemoApplication.java:13)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Now I can rename one of the properties to work around this problem but in the actual project I'm working on it'd lead to more changes.

Is it possible to keep the property name untouched?

Comment: Could you maybe provide more specifics about the particular behaviour you're looking for so that we can help you achieve that behaviour?
Relevant questions:
Have you tried using the inheritance type "Joined" as that might allow you the flexibility you're looking for?
Also have you tried reusing the super class back reference? I understand that you want it to be a RedAppleTree - maybe you can provide a method to return this and cast it? As it will be that type as it's a RedApple...

Comment: @MichaelWiles We plan to maintain multiple versions of a Rest API. So previously there was only one Apple/Tree, now there are `AppleV1`, `AppleV2`, etc. They share the same table with 70% common columns and 30% version-specific ones. Hence if they can provide the same interface, code'll be conciser where it only reads common fields and type doesn't matter.

Comment: Since both of your superclasses are annotated with "SINGLE_TABLE" you also have no way to ensure that a RedApple actually references an entry that corresponds to RedAppleTree. It may just as well refer to an entry of type "WalnutTree".

Comment: It would also be possible to simply remove the Tree from the subclass. That is the point of inheritance. There is no need to duplicate the property, particularly, since I would expect that you access the entry from the getters and setters.

Comment: @Nathan But why generic doesn't work then? I tried having e.g. `Apple<T>`, `RedApple extends Apple<RedTree>`, `Tree<T>`, `RedTree extends Tree<RedApple>`, then at compile time it should already know `RedTree` can only have `RedApple`s, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem to duplicate your "tree" property in both your superclass and your subclass. I believe that this example here will do what you want.

Tree.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Tree<APPLE extends Apple> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "tree", targetEntity = Apple.class)
    private Set<APPLE> apples = Sets.newHashSet();

    //... getters & setters
}
```

Apple.java

```
@Table(name = "apple")
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Apple<TREE extends Tree> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "tree_id")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Tree.class)
    private TREE tree;

}
```

RedAppleTree.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@DiscriminatorValue("RED")
public class RedAppleTree extends Tree<RedApple> {
}
```

RedApple.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "apple")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "colour")
@DiscriminatorValue("RED")
public class RedApple extends Apple<RedAppleTree> {
}
```

This creates the following DB tables

```
create table tree (
   colour varchar(31) not null,
    id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    primary key (id)
);
create table apple (
   colour varchar(31) not null,
    id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    tree_id bigint,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Then, when I run the following code

```
@Test
public void test() {

    RedAppleTree tree = new RedAppleTree();
    session.persist(tree);

    GreenAppleTree greenTree = new GreenAppleTree();
    session.persist(greenTree);

    RedApple apple = new RedApple();
    apple.setTree(tree);
    session.persist(apple);

    tree.getApples().add(apple);
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
    
    tree = session.get(RedAppleTree.class, tree.getId());

    System.err.println(session.createCriteria(RedAppleTree.class).list());
}
```

This results in the following SQL (ran with hibernate-sql-logging enabled)

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    tree
    (id, version, colour) 
values
    (default, ?, 'RED')
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    tree
    (id, version, colour) 
values
    (default, ?, 'GREEN')
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    apple
    (id, version, tree_id, colour) 
values
    (default, ?, ?, 'RED')
Hibernate: 
select
    redappletr0_.id as id2_409_0_,
    redappletr0_.version as version3_409_0_ 
from
    tree redappletr0_ 
where
    redappletr0_.id=? 
    and redappletr0_.colour='RED'
Hibernate: 
select
    this_.id as id2_409_0_,
    this_.version as version3_409_0_ 
from
    tree this_ 
where
    this_.colour='RED'
```

I believe that this ought to solve your basic problem.

Comment: I would have taken the same approach as you. Do you think is also possible to mantain data integrity overriding getters and setters in the subclasses?

Comment: you could certainly override the getters & setters but the generics provide the type-safety that you need unless someone is intent on exploiting type-erasure via reflections. but i'm not sure what benefit that would provide (at least in this use-case). hibernate allows you to place the annotation on either the field (as in the example here) or else on the getter. the restriction is that within the project you do this consistently. when you try to mix them, even in different classes, it causes lots of grief. i would try to avoid overriding them here unless there was a real compelling need.

Comment: https://github.com/Frederick888/java-dummy I'm getting `nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property com.example.demo.dao.Apple.tree has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type`?

Comment: Sorry just realised the bounty has expired. I'll add another if this can be resolved :)

Comment: With a couple tweaks I was able to reproduce your problem. Change the @OneToMany annotation to @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "tree", targetEntity = Apple.class)

Comment: I removed the colour column from the example, but when I added the column in (with your annotations) it worked just fine.

Comment: I checked out your github project and made a few changes and I have it running. I swapped the DB provider to run with hsql since I don't have your mysql server.

In Apple.java, change ManyToOne -> @ ManyToOne(targetEntity = Tree.class)
In Tree.java, change OneToMany -> @ OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "tree", targetEntity = Apple.class)

On both entities, add the class-level annotation -> @ Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

With these changes, your project runs successfully (using hsql).

Comment: though, i'm not sure that your auto-generate annotations and your other annotations are all correct (insertable = false, for example).

In the test, I added a few session.flush() and session.clear() operations and I had additional problems. I also changed:

JoinColumn(name = "tree_id", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
Once you change the JoinColumn I think that you will be able to fix any additional problems that you might have...

Comment: @Nathan Thank you and I'll check your solution out! Weird that I had no notifications for your replies.

Comment: @Nathan I have to wait for 24 hrs before I can give you the bounty... stupid restrictions lol

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that I have never encountered a similar problem, the logical thing, and a good practice would be to change the name of the property to differentiate which entity each one refers to, the compiler will tell you where to change it.

You could try indicating the child class in the relation as follows:

```
mappedBy = "tree", targetEntity = RedAppleTree.class
```

But I reiterate, the best option would be to change the name of the property, even if it involves more work.

Comment: No `targetEntity` didn't help. I also tried making `Tree` in `Apple.java` a generic, i.e. `T extends Tree`, and it didn't help either. Maybe it's only me but it sounds perfectly logical to have Apples growing on _some_ trees, RedApples on red trees and GreenApples on green trees... Depending what kind of Apple/Tree I've got, I should be able to use the same method to get Tree/Apple of the corresponding type.